# TeamCity build agent continually "Unable to start upgrade: Connection reset"

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-5.1

My TeamCity agent is contniually trying to download upgrades from the TeamCity server. It always downloads the files, then fails to start the installation, with the error:

WARN -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Unable to start upgrade: Connection reset

My server is running at http://localhost:9912

How do I stop this endless cycle?

Latest version of TeamCity downloaded from JetBrains

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're running the agent as an AD account rather than under the machine account.

Run the agent service under an account with administrative permissions for the upgrade. I don't remember the specifics of what it's trying to write but it won't if it's a standard user.